# ECLIPSE: How to disable "Google Java Indexer"

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed the Eclipse CodePro plugin . Its got a lot of little features like analysing complexity etc. However i have also noteiced my Eclipse has slowed down and all operations are often blocked by a task called "Google Java Indexer". I have tried looking at the CodePro options but have not been able to find an option to kill this task from doing its thing. At the very least which CodePro plugin runs this annoying thing so i can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Click your project -> properties (or alt+enter) -> click 'Builders' -> Uncheck whichever builder you don't want..